# SQL Server 2008 CLR aggregate function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, sqlclr

I have been looking at using a CLR aggregate to perform some complex financial calculations on  a series of data, but despite reading many articles on the subject and much fiddling I can't quite figure it out.

My input is a series of dates and values and I want to be able to do the following:

```
SELECT dbo.FinancialCalc(amount, date)
FROM (VALUES
            (-100000, '11/30/2011'),
            (-50000, '3/15/2012'),
            (-2500, '7/18/2012')         
            ) n(amount, date)
```

Here is my code so far:

```
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = 8000, Name = "FinancialCalc", IsInvariantToDuplicates = false, IsInvariantToNulls = true, IsInvariantToOrder = true, IsNullIfEmpty = true)]
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class FinancialCalc : IBinarySerialize
{    
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
    private List<DateTime> dates;
    private List<Double> values;

    public void Init()
    {        
        this.transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        this.dates = new List<DateTime>();
        this.values = new List<double>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlDouble amount, SqlDateTime date)
    {
        this.dates.Add(date.Value);
        this.values.Add(amount.Value);
    }

    public void Merge(FinancialCalc Group)
    {
       //is this needed?
    }

    public SqlDouble Terminate()
    {
       //here is where I would do the calc: return transactions.Calculate() or somethine
        return values.Sum();
    }

    public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
    {
        int itemCount = r.ReadInt16();

        for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)
        {
            this.values.Add(r.ReadDouble());          
        }
    }

    public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.values.Count);
        foreach (double s in this.values)
        {
            w.Write(s);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I successfully get the data in the SQL query into the `List<Transaction>` so that I can process it and return the calculated value?

Comment: Do you need the lists of dates and values, or is that just what you have so far? Is what you want just an (arbitrary) list of `Transaction` objects? And what does a `Transaction` object look like?

Comment: Those other lists were just for testing - the transactions are all that I would need. Transaction would look like `public class Transaction
{
    public double value {get;set;}
    public DateTime date {get;set;}
}
`

Comment: So, similar to the assumed one in my answer. All that should need changing (if you don't want to change your `Transaction` definition to match mine) is to use object initializer syntax rather than the constructor that I'd assumed, in `Accumulate` and `Read`.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume that a `Transaction` looks like this:

```
public class Transaction
{
  private readonly double _amount;
  private readonly DateTime _date;
  public Transaction(double amount,DateTime date){
    _amount = amount;
    _date = date;
  }
  public double Amount {get{return _amount;}}
  public DateTime Date {get{return _date;}}
}
```

Then I assume that what you actually want looks something like this:

```
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,
        //Play it safe, we don't know how large we'll get
        MaxByteSize = -1,
        Name = "FinancialCalc", IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,
        IsInvariantToNulls = true, IsInvariantToOrder = true,
        IsNullIfEmpty = true)]
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class FinancialCalc : IBinarySerialize
{    
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

    public void Init()
    {        
        this.transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlDouble amount, SqlDateTime date)
    {
        this.transactions.Add(new Transaction(date.Value,amount.Value));
    }

    public void Merge(FinancialCalc Group)
    {
       //Yes, you do need this. Group contains another set of transactions
       //and is going to disappear after this method has been called
       this.transactions.AddRange(Group.transactions);
    }

    public SqlDouble Terminate()
    {
        //Do your calculation based on the content of transactions
        return new SqlDouble(transactions.Sum(t=>t.Amount));
    }

    public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
    {
        int itemCount = r.ReadInt16();

        for (int i = 0; i <= itemCount - 1; i++)
        {
            this.transactions.Add(new Transaction(r.ReadDouble(),
                                       new DateTime(r.ReadInt64()));          
        }
    }

    public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(this.transactions.Count);
        foreach (var t in this.transactions)
        {
            w.Write(t.Amount);
            w.Write(t.Date.ToBinary());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Damien, much appreciated. I am getting an error though when deploying - ` CREATE AGGREGATE failed because type 'FinancialCalc' does not conform to UDAGG specification due to field 'CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1'.` I assume this is because of the LINQ in the terminate method, which I won't need anyway.

Comment: @woggles - yes, I just composed this by hand, I didn't attempt to compile it or add it to a SQL Server instance :-(

Comment: Almost there :) Another issue when converting the date I think: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.
Parameter name: ticks` when running the sql

Comment: @woggles, are you trying to use a conversion method other than `dateTimeValue = sqlDateTimeValue.Value`?